# What are the benefits for Monero of running a mipseed node? Why would one want to generate a vanity prefix for the i2p address?

Tags: i2p, i2p-zero

In a guide [on how to run a node over i2p-zero](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/node-i2p-zero.html) there is a reference to another, almost identical guide on [how to run a **mipseed** (short for **monero I2P seed**) node](https://github.com/i2p-zero/i2p-zero/blob/master/mipseed.md).
I noticed that the two guides differ only in backing up of `~/.i2p-zero/config/tunnels.json` (which is present in the mipseed guide) and in vanity prefix generation.
Why would one want to generate a vanity prefix for the i2p address on its generation?

Other than the generation of an optional vanity prefix, I understand that a mipseed node that has had the same address for years is somewhat
more trusted and can perhaps be listed somewhere, e.g. in [getmonero.org](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/) as the one to be added with `--add-peer` on launching `monerod`. I also assume that it is easier for such a node to find peers when compared to a node whose address was created just five minutes ago. Am I correct in my understanding?
Am I missing any other differences between running a node over i2p-zero and running a mipseed node?